# Macro- Copy and paste a single row for every cell in another column multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I need help to copy and paste a single row for every cell in another column multiple times starting in the second row.

The raw data looks like this

[image: Raw Data]

I need it to look like this
[image]

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="data1", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet2!R2C5:R2C7" 
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("data1").Comment = "" Range("data1").Copy 
 Range("B1").Select ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
```

Here is where I get lost. I am not sure how to loop it down and then keep it going and copy column a down and then the defined range again.

I also tried this:

```
    Dim LastRow As Variant
    Dim LastRowA As Variant
    Dim Row As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Store_Item_copy")
        LastRow = .Range("A2" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Range("A2" & LastRow).Copy

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        i = i + 1

        With Sheets("Store_Item_copy")
            LastRowA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        LastRowA.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

    Next i
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: @srj added code to example

Comment: Is there always a full set of repeated items in Column A? i.e. 600,700,800,900 or multiples thereof e.g. 600,700,800,900,600,700,800,900?

Comment: @Qharr  I essentially need every line on the right for every value in A..

So if there are 4 values in column a  and 10 values on the right, each value in a should appear with every value from the right. So there would be 40 rows total on the sheet  (4x10=40)

Comment: Give my answer a try and i will update if there are cases where it doesn't quite do what was expected.

Comment: @QHarr When I run the macro, nothing happens. Not sure if theres some setting I need to have. I am using excel 2016

Comment: No. You put it in a standard module and make sure to change this line to the right worksheet  Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: It is based on your data being set up as shown in the image in the question

Comment: @Qharr Hi When i do i get a subscript out of range error

Comment: It happens at the worksheet name part

Comment: Did you change to the worksheet containing your data? Maybe Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Store_Item_copy")

Comment: And is all the raw data in one sheet?

Comment: I changed it to Set wsSource = ActiveSheet   and it worked thanks!.

Not sure why the naming wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateColumns()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")       'Change as appropriate

    Dim yearArr()

    yearArr = wsSource.Range("E2:F" & wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim storesArr()

    storesArr = wsSource.Range("A2:C" & wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim resultArr()
    ReDim resultArr(1 To UBound(storesArr, 1) * UBound(yearArr, 1), 1 To 3)

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim counter2 As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    For x = 1 To UBound(yearArr, 1)

        counter2 = counter2 + 1

        For y = 1 To UBound(storesArr, 1)

            counter = counter + 1

            resultArr(counter, 1) = storesArr(y, 1)
            resultArr(counter, 2) = yearArr(counter2, 1)
            resultArr(counter, 3) = yearArr(counter2, 2)

        Next y

    Next x

    wsSource.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(resultArr, 1), UBound(resultArr, 2)).Value = resultArr

End Sub
```